# Client says it is connected to server, but server doesn't process client

Tags: c++, chat, winsock

I am writing a console chat program and I am learning the WinSock2 library as I write it. So far I have a working server and client, the only problem is that the server doesn't process the client, but the client says it is connected. Right now there is no functionality other than testing if the connection works which it doesn't. The server is suppose to print out a message when it has successfully accepted a client. I've been trying to figure this out but can't. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Server Header:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "winsock.h"

class Server
{
    public:
        Server(int port);
        ~Server();
    private:
        const int port;

        std::string error;

        WORD wVersion;
        WSADATA wsaData;

        SOCKET hSocket;

        bool init();

        bool setupSocket();
        void startServer();

        void closeConnection();
};

#endif
```

Server:

```
#include "Server.h"

Server::Server(int port) : port(port), wVersion(MAKEWORD(2, 2))
{
    if (init()) {
        std::cout << "Server successfully setup" << std::endl << std::endl;
        startServer();
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error: " + error << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        std::cin.get();
    }
}

bool Server::init()
{
    return setupSocket();
}

bool Server::setupSocket()
{
    int iResult = WSAStartup(wVersion, &wsaData);

    if (iResult) {
        error = "Problem initializating WinSock2";
        return false;
    } else if (wsaData.wVersion != wVersion) {
        error = "Incorrect WinSock version";
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "WinSock initialized" << std::endl;

    sockaddr_in sockAddr;
    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (hSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        error = "Problem setting up socket";
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Socket setup" << std::endl;

    if (bind(hSocket, (LPSOCKADDR) &sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {  
        error = "Problem binding socket";
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Socket binded to port" << std::endl;

    listen(hSocket, SOMAXCONN);

    std::cout << "Server is now listening on port " << port << std::endl;

    SOCKET client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (client == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        error = "Problem setting up socket";
        return false;
    }

    if (client = accept(hSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&sockAddr, NULL)) {
        std::cout << "A client connected!";
    }

    return true;
    }

     void Server::startServer()
     {
    std::string consoleInput;

    while (true) {
        std::cin >> consoleInput;
        std::cout << consoleInput << std::endl;
    }
}

void Server::closeConnection()
{
    if (hSocket) {
        closesocket(hSocket);
    }

    WSACleanup();
}

Server::~Server()
{
    closeConnection();
}
```

Client Header:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "WinSock.h"

class Client
{
    public:
        Client(std::string name);

        bool connectToServer(char ip[], int port);

        ~Client();
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string error;

        WORD wVersion;
        WSADATA wsaData;

        SOCKET hSocket;


};

#endif
```

Client:

```
#include "Client.h"


Client::Client(std::string name) : name(name), wVersion(MAKEWORD(2,2))
{
}

bool Client::connectToServer(char ip[], int port)
{
    int iResult = WSAStartup(wVersion, &wsaData);

    if (iResult) {
        error = "Problem initializating WinSock2";
        return false;
    } else if (wsaData.wVersion != wVersion) {
        error = "Incorrect WinSock version";
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "WinSock initialized" << std::endl;

    sockaddr_in sockAddr;
    sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(ip);

    hSocket = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (hSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        error = "Problem setting up socket";
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Socket setup" << std::endl;

    if (connect(hSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        error = "Problem connecting to server";
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Connected to server!";

    return true;
}

Client::~Client()
{
}
```

Comment: Well, when you ran the server under a debugger, did the accept() call return?

Comment: Why does setupSocket() make 2 sockets?

Comment: @brianbeuning One is a listening socket and one is a client socket. I plan to allow multiple connections later.

Comment: @RyanPrintup You only need to make the listening socket, the accept call returns a new socket connected to the client.